# How to create bootable USB that contain multiple programs?

Tags: boot, usb

I want to create bootable USB and add programs like GParted, Kaspersky Resque Disk, Windows 7 Repair Disk and lot of others that can be loaded on boot. 
I know how to create bootable USB but how to add the programs so when the machine boots to show a simple interface with the programs list so i can choose which program to start.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this program when trying to do a similar thing and it worked for me: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

It is called YUMI (your universal multiboot installer). It's really simple to use. Just download and run the program following the on screen instructions.

Here's the download link: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/YUMI-0.1.0.4.exe

Comment: Have you tried to add Hiren's BootCD to USB with YUMI and then add other programs?

Comment: I haven't ever used that before. I don't know if it would work or not, there's no harm in testing I suppose.